# smarty3 detection if template was included by {include}

Tags: php, smarty, smarty3

In smarty3, is there a way to find out if a smarty template was included my the  {include} tag? 
I know i just could do it that way for example:

```
{include file="blahblah.tpl" included=1}
```

And inside blahblah.tpl

```
{if $included==1}
  yadda yadda yadda 
{/if}
```

I just want to know if there's a simpler way.

Answer (score 0):

Before including your template file , you can check with **[template_exists()](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/api.template.exists.tpl)**, to see if  template exists

```
if( !$smarty->template_exists($mid_template) ){
    $mid_template = 'page_not_found.tpl';
} else {
    $mid_template = 'blahblah.tpl';
}
$smarty->assign('content_template', $mid_template);
```

Comment: thanks, but thats not what i'm looking for. i'd like to know if it's possible to find out, how a template was invoked. like in your example, by the smarty object, or like in my example, by the {include } smarty tag.